# How can I use subject-conflicts in a Authzforce request?

Tags: java, authorization, xacml, abac, authzforce

How can I use urn:oasis:names:tc:xacml:1.0:subject:subject-conflicts in a Authzforce request? The code below gives a red underline at XACML_1_0_SUBJECT_CONFLICTS. Do I miss an import or I'm a just using it the wrong way?

```
final AttributeFqn subjectIdAttributeId = AttributeFqns.newInstance(XACML_1_0_ACCESS_SUBJECT.value(), Optional.empty(), XACML_1_0_SUBJECT_CONFLICTS);
    final AttributeBag<?> subjectIdAttributeValues = Bags.singletonAttributeBag(StandardDatatypes.STRING, new StringValue("1"));
    requestBuilder.putNamedAttributeIfAbsent(subjectIdAttributeId, subjectIdAttributeValues);
```

Comment: What is your error?

Comment: Looks like  XACML_1_0_SUBJECT_CONFLICTS is undefined. Have you defined this variable anywhere? It is certainly not defined in AuthzForce.